# Understand the /etc/inittab

Tags: linux, terminal, init-script, init, sysvinit

I am using the following `/etc/inittab` file (systemv):

```
# /etc/inittab: init(8) configuration.
# $Id: inittab,v 1.91 2002/01/25 13:35:21 miquels Exp $

# The default runlevel.
id:5:initdefault:

# Boot-time system configuration/initialization script.
# This is run first except when booting in emergency (-b) mode.

si::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS

# What to do in single-user mode.
~~:S:wait:/sbin/sulogin

# /etc/init.d executes the S and K scripts upon change
# of runlevel.
#
# Runlevel 0 is halt.
# Runlevel 1 is single-user.
# Runlevels 2-5 are multi-user.
# Runlevel 6 is reboot.

l0:0:wait:/etc/init.d/rc 0
l1:1:wait:/etc/init.d/rc 1
l2:2:wait:/etc/init.d/rc 2
l3:3:wait:/etc/init.d/rc 3
l4:4:wait:/etc/init.d/rc 4
l5:5:wait:/etc/init.d/rc 5
l6:6:wait:/etc/init.d/rc 6
# Normally not reached, but fallthrough in case of emergency.
z6:6:respawn:/sbin/sulogin
S0:12345:respawn:/sbin/getty -L 115200 ttyS0
```

In order to understand how things really work I'll appreciate if your answers to 1-3 you'll distinguish between two situations:

1. I'm connected to my system using a serial port.
2. I have a "regular" desktop pc.

Questions:

1. If I'll add another getty line, once linux startup I will see two separate terminals?
2. If I open several getty lines, how I assigned which getty will run my
   `si::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS` command and which getty will run the other script's commands? (the ones who run scripts according to the system run level)

   in other words: in the `/etc/inittab` file - can i assign different commands to different gettys? (i mean to the terminals which will open by these gettys)
3. the last script in /etc/init.d/rc5 folder run the following command:

   ```
   su nobody -c /bin/sh
   ```

   and the output is:

   ```
   sh: cannot set terminal process group (1618): Inappropriate ioctl for device
   sh: no job control in this shell
   sh-4.3$ whoami
   nobody
   ```

   So I verified that i am nobody but why it writes the first two lines?
   also why the prompt is sh-4.3$ and not nobody@...
4. I'm using serial connection. Can I change the /etc/inittab file and the last script that will run by init in order to:

   1. run a program before login as low privileged user (init process will wait for termination)
   2. once the program exits get the regular login prompt to my system
   3. what is the best way to create a low privileged user and let him run this program during init process (if I don't want to use the nobody user)

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, assuming the line is given a unique identifier and the configured terminal line is available:

   ```
   S1:12345:respawn:/sbin/getty -L 115200 ttyS1
   ```

   will open a terminal on the serial port attached to `ttyS1`.
2. Lines in `inittab` aren’t sequential, or related to a login. Each line describes an action to be taken in a given set of runlevels. Thus `si::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS` specifies that `init` should run `/etc/init.d/rcS` when it handles system initialisation; this happens before logins are possible. (See [the `inittab(5)` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/inittab.5) for details).

   To assign different commands to different `getty`s on specific terminals, you’d configure the `getty` invocation itself, for example by changing the `login` program it starts (the `-l` option in most `getty` implementations):

   ```
   S0:12345:respawn:/sbin/getty -L 115200 -l /bin/my-t0-login ttyS0
   S1:12345:respawn:/sbin/getty -L 115200 -l /bin/my-t1-login ttyS1
   ```
3. `/etc/init.d/rc 5` runs before logins are possible, and the programs it runs aren’t connected to a terminal (“properly”, which is what `getty` does – it opens the terminal for you and connects the programs it starts to it), so when `su nobody -c /bin/sh` is invoked, the shell doesn’t find the terminal setup it expects, and disables job control as a result. The `sh-4.3$` prompt is Bash 4.3’s default prompt when run as `/bin/sh`.
4. If your program is only supposed to run once a user starts logging in, then you can hook it into the login sequence used by `getty`; but such a program would run as root. Depending on what you’re after exactly, you’d probably be better off using an initscript rather than `/etc/inittab` customisation, or `sudo` and the shell’s startup scripts.

Comment: thanks for your replay. Can I ask for a smail clarification regards sec.2?   how can I edit the login command for each different getty?

Comment: Done, see the update.

Comment: thank you! just to check if I understood correctly:     by default the getty process will run the /bin/login command which executes the process responsible for system login.    Now the getty will run a different command , every command that I'll choose , and will not call to the system login process as before...   am i right?

Comment: Yes, that’s right. The key is getting `getty` to open the TTY for you; its normal behaviour is to wait for a login name, then run `login`, connected to the TTY; `login` waits for the password, checks it and starts the shell, also connected to the TTY. If you replace the `login` part, you’ll need to make sure your replacement program behaves like `login`.

Comment: For example if I want to skip the login phase - to be able to open my system with root user without entering any user name or password.  I can use: S0:12345:respawn:/sbin/getty -L 115200 -l -/bin/sh ttyS0 or to use: S0:12345:respawn:/sbin/getty -L 115200 -l [my_script_path] ttyS0 and inside the script i'll run the -/bin/sh command and others?

Comment: Look at `getty`’s `-a` option for auto-login. If you want to do several things you’d use a script, yes, not `/bin/sh` directly.

Comment: I dont have the -a option. Thats why I'm asking..    Why you saying not to run /bin/sh directly from getty?

Comment: It might be worth changing your `getty` ;-) (I use `agetty`). You’re asking how to run a command just before giving a shell to a connecting user; if you want to do that, it seems more appropriate to have `getty` run a shell script which does everything you want, rather than starting a shell directly (because then, how do you run the command you wanted to run initially, only on that terminal? it’s doable but means keeping track of things across various files).

Comment: Your answers helped me a lot! thank you very much.   I still have something missing to complete the big picture.  Can I edit my question instead of asking you here? I think it can help others

Comment: The key to a question edit is whether it invalidates existing answers. If it clarifies the initial question, helping answer writers to produce better questions, then it’s appropriate; otherwise, especially if it requires answers to be expanded or rewritten to remain valid (assuming they did answer the initial question), it should perhaps be a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

Yes, by adding more `getty` lines you can get more terminals in parallel. Only one `getty` can be associated with one terminal device at a time, so only one `getty` per serial port is possible. On a regular desktop PC, the Linux kernel defines a number of virtual consoles, accessible using the <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>FX</kbd> key combinations and corresponding to `/dev/ttyX` devices (X = a number). The exact setup may vary between distributions, but usually on mainstream distributions, the first 6 or so `/dev/ttyX` devices have `getty`s configured for them when the system is running normally. You can use `openvt` and `deallocvt` commands to add or remove virtual consoles and start processes (which can be any processes, not necessarily `getty`s) on them.

`/dev/tty0` is special: it refers to whichever virtual console is the currently selected one. `/dev/console` is a similar special device, pointing to whatever TTY device is defined as the primary kernel-level system console. On desktop systems, it is effectively an alias to `/dev/tty0` by default, but by using the `console=` boot option you could switch it to a serial port. On e.g. some embedded architectures it might be a serial port by default. Utilities like `xconsole` can also act as an additional output for `/dev/console`.

Back when computers were big multi-cabinet things in dedicated computer rooms, sending a message to `/dev/console` would have been a way to reach the on-duty system operator physically near the computer, which might have been useful for requests to e.g. change tapes or disk packs. On modern systems, messages sent specifically to `/dev/console` are usually boot/shutdown messages, or possibly a last-resort channel for urgent alarms about failure conditions that might impact network or storage access, or even involve a kernel crash: "a person in charge of the physical hardware needs to see this  and the usual log files are unusable for some reason."

---

Question 2:

I'm afraid you have a misconception here. The `sysinit` line and other `/etc/inittab` lines are not associated with `getty` processes at all. Each command executed from `inittab`, unless otherwise specified, has its standard input, output and error streams associated with `/dev/console`.

The `getty` lines actually specify the TTY device they will be using, and the `getty` process has code built in that will assign that TTY device for themselves and all their child processes unless/until the user runs a shell and chooses to redirect those streams some other way. That and initializing the settings of the TTY device are the biggest part of `getty`'s purpose: displaying `/etc/issue` and the login prompt, accepting the username, setting the TERM environment variable and starting the next step of the TTY login process (usually `/bin/login` but customizable) are effectively just minor parts.

Note that there is a convention that for the TTY devices, the two-character ID field in the first column of the `inittab` line should match the name of the TTY device in question after the `/dev/tty` prefix, so `/dev/ttyS0` will get an inittab line ID of `S0`, and so on. For stuff that is not necessarily associated with any TTY at all (or just outputs emergency stuff to /dev/console if needed), the ID can be anything that does not conflict with the TTY device line IDs.

(Back in the day when serial-attached terminals were the norm, getting the settings of the TTY device right for the terminal at the other end of the line, and resetting that terminal to a known state for login were non-trivial tasks, since there were many competing terminal type standards.)

If you configure an `inittab` line to run a script, you could, for example, see if a particular `/dev/ttyX` virtual console device exists. If it does not, you can use `openvt -c X <command>` to create the virtual console and start a command on it; if the virtual console device already exists, you can simply start whatever command you want with standard input, output and error redirected to it. For example, you could specify an inittab line like this:

```
6:345:respawn:/usr/local/sbin/myscript
```

and then `/usr/local/sbin/myscript` with something like this (disclaimer: not tested, I don't have a system with SysVinit at hand right now, feel free to edit if you can improve this):

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -c /dev/tty6 ]; then
    exec <some command> </dev/tty6 >/dev/tty6 2>&1
else
    exec openvt -c 6 -w <some command>
fi
```

`respawn` in the `inittab` line makes sure the process will automatically be restarted if it dies for any reason. `345` is the list of SysVinit runlevels this process should run on. If you need it to run on all regular runlevels, enter `12345`.

Note, this works as intended only if the inittab line is placed after the `sysinit` line, so the initialization of `udev` can be assumed to be complete. If you want to do this early in the init process, you may have to take care of creating the actual device nodes for devices that have drivers already loaded first; once `udev` is running, it should create device nodes automatically as device drivers are initialized.

If using a serial port, the `openvt` command will not apply.

So yes, you definitely can attach different commands to different TTY devices. It helps if the commands have built-in facilities for that like `getty`s do, but you can do it with scripting too.

(If you set up something more complicated than a simple `tail -f` to permanently view some log in an otherwise-unused virtual console, you should read `man setsid` and see if it is applicable to what you're planning.)

---

Question 3:

There is more to initializing a TTY session for a particular non-root user than just starting a shell with `su`.

The error messages

```
sh: cannot set terminal process group (1618): Inappropriate ioctl for device
sh: no job control in this shell
```

are probably caused by the shell being associated by the `/dev/console` device rather than a specific TTY device. Since `/dev/console` is just an alias to whatever is the current system console, it won't have the full set of TTY control ioctl functions available to it.

If there is no login script to assign a more useful value to the `PS1` environment variable, the default prompt for `/bin/sh` can be simply `sh-<version>$`.

---

Question 4:

Yes, you can. You should specify the "last script" as a `wait`-type line in `inittab`, and place it *before* the `getty` line corresponding to your serial line.

Without knowing a lot more details about your environment, it will be very difficult to say which would be the *best* way to create a low-privilege user for such purposes.

Comment: thanks! small q plz: when init process invokes other processes according to the suitable runlevel scripts , I can see that! if I'll run program from one of these scripts I'll see it executing. From my understanding - if I can see it (inside the terminal) there must be a getty who opened this first terminal for me. I guess the ttys0 getty is the one opened this first stty for me. What's the connection of /dev/console to that?   and if I write 4 scripts, same runlevel, but I want each will run in different getty (but the init process is the one that runs these scripts) how can i do that?

Comment: `getty` is a process; what you are talking about is a **TTY device**. The kernel opened the first one for you and for the init scripts; `/dev/console` is an alias to "the first TTY device that was opened and used by the kernel". If your user account has the permissions for read+write access to a TTY device, you can just start using it (no `getty` needed), but it might be a good idea to set the TERM variable correctly: `TERM=linux top </dev/tty8 >/dev/tty8 2>&1 &` or `TERM=vt100 top </dev/ttyS1 >/dev/ttyS1 2>&1 &` will start the `top` command on the 8th virtual console or the 2nd serial port.

Comment: If you attempt to run a process on a TTY device that already has a `getty` process on it, it will make a mess of the input&output, as the two processes will fight for the input and their outputs will get mixed up together. The `getty` processes are started only after the `/etc/init.d/rc 5` and any scripts started by it have *finished*.

Comment: thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Just now a second (long!) answer has been posted. I must say the first one explains quite well. At the moment I want to comment on point three: It is less a question of timing, but of processes controlling a "real virtual" tty, and not just a "console dummy".

Before you can start a shell "with job control", you have to set up i.e. open a ttyN. The "generic" command is `getty`. *From that* tty-something you get you can start a shell, not just *after* that.

It is like trying to first start a window manager, and then xorg, instead of "booting" them together with xinit. I think. "session leader".

---

Because of

```
xx:12:...:program
```

and, contrarily:

```
aa:1:...:pr_1
bb:1:...:pr_2
```

...you get a N:M relation (you also get a mess if you abuse -- many RLs each with many different progs). You can go far with that, but since ever different kinds of RC-"standards" have taken over. "Runcoms". With them, inittab looks simple, but all the complexity is in these scripts.

But your inittab looks simple and correct - only the last comment, and the "z6" entry...

Maybe your "su nobody" just needs a "getty ... ttyN" before / around. `su` instead of `login`, and no respawn. Should at least give another error message than "inappropriate".

---

Conclusion (after reading 2nd answer): You don't need a complicated `init.d` system, the raw inittab is flexible enough. Just have to get the concept and the details right.

You could set up three runlevels: one with ttyNs, one with ttySN, and one RL that starts both. It is a boot parameter you can add with the boot loader. Runlevel "5" in your case is only default. You choose a kernel, a root=, and a runlevel to init into.

---

The "respawn" action is what sysvinit was/is actually needed for. Much more it does not do, and less would have been possible to implement in a script. But if you exit (or crash) the "last" shell level, you need a safety net.

sysvinit can even detect a misconfig by erroring "spawning too fast -- ignoring for 5 minutes...".